# When i knit my R markdown it doesn't show leaflet after running showing a Wordcloud

Tags: html, r, leaflet, markdown, wordcloud2

Basically when I knit the R markdown the file shows just the Wordcloud, and not the leaflet map.
If I invert the order everything works fine.

Any suggestion?

My chunks here:

```
library(tidytext)
library(wordcloud2)

wordcloud_data <- listings_NA%>%
  select(name)%>%
  unnest_tokens(input = name, output = word, token = "words")%>%
  count(word, sort = TRUE)%>%
  filter(n>10)

wordcloud2(wordcloud_data,
          shape = "diamond", 
          color = "White",
          backgroundColor = "steelblue",
          fontFamily = "Georgia")
```

```
print(leaflet(listings_NA %>%
          select(latitude, longitude, neighbourhood, price))%>%
  setView(lat = 40.863, lng =  14.2767,zoom = 12)%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()))
```

Comment: You need to show us a complete document if you want help debugging.  Drop everything except these two chunks (and whatever setup they need), and put that in your post instead of a non-reproducible subset.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.